# Configure firewall rules for kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to configure firewall rules for kubernetes service to allow restricted access to my mongo pod when running a load balancer service. I would like to know how to specify the ip range because we have our own internal firewall?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

From https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-cloud-provider-firewall/#restrict-access-for-loadbalancer-service:

> When using a Service with spec.type: LoadBalancer, you can specify the IP ranges that are allowed to access the load balancer by using spec.loadBalancerSourceRanges. This field takes a list of IP CIDR ranges, which Kubernetes will use to configure firewall exceptions. This feature is currently supported on Google Compute Engine, Google Container Engine and AWS. This field will be ignored if the cloud provider does not support the feature.

This `loadBalancerSourceRanges` property should help in your case.